# Retrieving all roles from RoleManager throws exception asp.net identity

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, role-manager

When I try to get roles from `RoleManager`, I get list of very strange list of objects,

[image: List of objects]

How I retrieve my roles:

```
public AppRoleManager RoleManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppRoleManager>();
    }
}

public IEnumerable<AppRole> GetRoles()
{
    return RoleManager.Roles.ToList();
}
```

I didn't have this problem before, but I guess it might have something to do that I moved my whole web application with database to Azure? Could anyone point finger how to fix this?

So my problem is that when I load my page with that list passed as a model, it will throw exception error without any exception details. Just server error throws up.

Note: getting same way my user's `UserManager` works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why this didn't work. I had a different version of System.Web.Mvc in my other project which handles identity than my web project. Upgrading to same version I didnt get anymore errors for retrieving roles from RoleManager. Strange that this didnt happen when I was gettin Roles from UserManager..